# can we AND two steps in robot framework?

Tags: database, if-statement, conditional-statements, robotframework

here for example i have a GUI verification of some flag is on/off and the same is dependent on the database flag too.
in Robot Framework if I have written one step for verifying the GUI flag ad in other I've written the database flag verification.
Can I AND these two steps and make a condition If both condition1 and condition 2 is true then log a message else log another message. ?

example :

```
${takingorderstatus_1}  Set Variable    1           
Log ${takingorderstatus_1}                      
${takingorderstatus_0}  Set Variable    0                   
Log ${takingorderstatus_0}                      
Run Keyword If  ${takingorderstatus_1} == 1 Log Is taking orders is active on GUI               
Run Keyword Unless  ${takingorderstatus_0} == 0 Log Is taking orders is not active on GUI               
Connect To Database pymysql NEW_PROD_DUMP   ${UserName} ${Password} ${DatabaseHost} ${Port} 
Check If Exists In Database SELECT dp.`outletName`, dp.`isActive` AS 'DistributionPointActive', cpd.`isActive` AS 'OnChannelPartnerActive', cpd.`channelPartnerOutletName`, cpd.`channelPartnerURL` FROM ChannelPartnerDistributionPointIdMapping cpd LEFT JOIN DistributionPoint dp ON dp.id = cpd.`distributionPointId` WHERE cpd.`channelPartnerId` = 2 AND cpd.`distributionPointId` = 2                        
@{QueryResult}  Query   SELECT dp.`outletName`, dp.`isActive` AS 'DistributionPointActive', cpd.`isActive` AS 'OnChannelPartnerActive', cpd.`channelPartnerOutletName`, cpd.`channelPartnerURL` \ FROM ChannelPartnerDistributionPointIdMapping cpd LEFT JOIN DistributionPoint dp ON dp.id = cpd.`distributionPointId` WHERE cpd.`channelPartnerId` = 2 AND cpd.`distributionPointId` = 2                  
Log @{QueryResult}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Run Keyword If  ${value} >= 1 and $string == value    Log To Console    Two conditions
```

Note that `and` is case-sensitive; `AND` does not work. OR follows the same conventions.

Comment: This will fail if `${string}` contains a single quote. You might want to use `$string` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know of this and I have never encountered in this. Maybe control variables do not have single quotes that often.

Comment: Also, `=>` is not valid syntax for an expression.